# Meteor setTimeout in method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection called Games with method updateGame. I want to start game on client if playersCount = 4, so I want to update field hasStarted after 4 seconds. I tried it with bluebird promises, but got this error: "Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment."

```
export const updateGame = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'games.updateGame',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    gameId: { type: String },
  }).validator(),
  run({ gameId }) {
    const game = Games.findOne(gameId);
    let playersCount = game.playersCount + 1;
    let isRunning = false;
    if (playersCount === 4) {
      isRunning = true;
      startAfterDelay(gameId, 4000);
    }
    Games.update(gameId, {
      $set: { 
        playersCount,
        isRunning
      },
    });
  },
});

const startAfterDelay = function(gameId, delay) {  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Meteor.wrapAsync(
        Games.update(gameId, {
          $set: { 
            hasStarted: true
          },
        })
      );
    }, delay)
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Meteor.setInterval](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_setinterval)?

Comment: yes "Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set timers inside simulations"

Comment: Have you used `Meteor.bindEnvironment` to wrap the callback of `Promise`? You can't access the `Meteor` context inside of a callback from a non-Meteor library without doing so.